# microphone is not working on my html page

Tags: javascript, html

I use webkitspeechrecognition for speech recognition,that worked when i write the script in console,but as i integrate it with html page it shows microphone is not allowed for this page,is there any problem with my code?
My code is here

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="start" onclick="recognize()">Start</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function recognize(){
    console.log("recognize")
    var sr=new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    sr.start();
    sr.onresult=function(event){
    console.log(event.results[0][0].transcript)
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running the html file as localhost/webserver or through file:// ?

Comment: yes i am running this as localhost

Comment: does [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330977/webkitspeechrecognition-no-longer-prompts-for-permission) help?

Comment: Try clearing your cache.

Comment: I tried after clearing the cache too,but still its not working.

Comment: how to run the page using prototypes?@JaromandaX